# How can I create a vs.net website project from existing files on a server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am taking over a project that has all the files on the server.  It seems the project was build using a website project type.

What is the best way for me to re-create a vs.net solution?

**Update**
So I pulled all the files down, saved the solution.

**Trying to Run the application but it says 'getting files from server...", how to I configure it to run locally now?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is copy all of the files locally first

Then create a new empty solution

Then right click and Open Existing Project (website)

Point to the existing file folder on your local machine

and there you should have all your files in working order.

Comment: sorry I don't have visual studio open in front of me for the exact wording.